# Using a PHP $_GET Variable in an Embedded SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

So I have my PHP page and in the address bar it says something like this:

```
http://blabla/ClientStats.php?client=blabla
```

I had used the $_GET['CLIENT'] variable successfully until I wanted to access it inside an SQL query, like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT ... ... ... FROM ... ... ... WHERE Client = '" + $_GET['CLIENT'] + "'";
?>
```

The query is a lot more complex than that, but will that "WHERE" statement work?

I'd tried to get this working quite a few different ways with no success so if I could find out the way today to get it working tomorrow that would be great (can't even remember if I tried doing it as I wrote above!).

So will that work, if not how should I do it?

Comment: Your code is vurnerable to SQL injections. Please fix that problem first. Then you don't have your actual problem any more. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: PHP uses `.` for string concatenation, not `+`. Besides that, read the previous comments.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Also: the string concatenation operator in PHP is `.`, not `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add '.' instead of  '+'.  it should be

```
$query = "SELECT ... ... ... FROM ... ... ... WHERE Client = '" . $_GET['CLIENT'] . "'";
```

but before that , please check your code since it is vurnerable to SQL injections

Answer (score 2):

That's not a good idea, as you are using unchecked user input within an sql query, which will lead to a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your original question, yes it will work but I think you'll find its rather frowned upon as it opens huge security vulnerabilities in your application.

What I do is store the values in a variable and then sanatize the input:

Example:

```
$client = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CLIENT']);
```

Comment: What you do is **wrong**. Neither of those sanitizations are suitable for SQL.

Comment: Sorry, i was showing an example. I don't code PHP. Updated answer to correct function.

Answer (score 0):

you must escape using *_real_escape_string ,otherwise your query is capable of sql injection attak 
therefore use like this

```
$client = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CLIENT']);//if using mysql

<?php
$query = "SELECT ... ... ... FROM ... ... ... WHERE Client = '".$client. "'";
?>
```